# Error en php excel Exception has occurred. Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

Tags: php, phpexcel

Exception has occurred.
Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

me aparece el error anterior al intentar cargar el php mediante la siguiente linea, require_once dirname(**FILE**) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

pero ocurre concretamente en el autoloader.php en las ultimas lineas donde se define  require($pClassFilePath); ya e intentando varias cosas pero no se por que no funciona, a continuacion el codigo del autoloader.php

```
    <?php

PHPExcel_Autoloader::register();
//    As we always try to run the autoloader before anything else, we can use it to do a few
//        simple checks and initialisations
//PHPExcel_Shared_ZipStreamWrapper::register();
// check mbstring.func_overload
if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2) {
    throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Multibyte function overloading in PHP must be disabled for string functions (2).');
}
PHPExcel_Shared_String::buildCharacterSets();

/**
 * PHPExcel
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 - 2015 PHPExcel
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 * @category   PHPExcel
 * @package    PHPExcel
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006 - 2015 PHPExcel (http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel)
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt    LGPL
 * @version    ##VERSION##, ##DATE##
 */
class PHPExcel_Autoloader
{
    /**
     * Register the Autoloader with SPL
     *
     */
    public static function register()
    {
        if (function_exists('__autoload')) {
            // Register any existing autoloader function with SPL, so we don't get any clashes
            spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
        }
        // Register ourselves with SPL
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
            return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'load'));
        } else {
            return spl_autoload_register(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'load'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Autoload a class identified by name
     *
     * @param    string    $pClassName        Name of the object to load
     */
    public static function load($pClassName)
    {
        if ((class_exists($pClassName, false)) || (strpos($pClassName, 'PHPExcel') !== 0)) {
            // Either already loaded, or not a PHPExcel class request
            return false;
        }

        $pClassFilePath = PHPEXCEL_ROOT .
            str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pClassName) .
            '.php';

        if ((stream_resolve_include_path($pClassFilePath) === false)) {
            // Can't load
            return false;
        }

        require($pClassFilePath);
    }
}
```

por favor alguien que allá tenido este error antes que me pueda colaborar, ya que cualquier cambio que le hago resulta fallido

Comment: PhpExcel es un proyecto antiguo y abandonado, te recomiendo migrar a [PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)

Comment: Vale, voy a desarrolarlo con phpspreadsheet entonces, muchas gracias

Comment: De todos modos vas a seguir teniendo el aviso de obsolescencia, porque el mismo es debido a la forma en que construyes la cadena. [Revisa lo explicado en este RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access)  y corrige en tu código la práctica obsoleta al respecto, pues aunque cambies a PHPSpreadSheet (lo cual es recomendable) el problema seguirá pues ocurre porque intentas acceder a elementos de un array mediante la notación `{N}`, donde `N` es el índice del elemento. En el RFC antes citado se acordó que haya una sola notación: `[N]` (la habitual), para evitar confusiones.

Comment: Ya realice la instalación de PhpSpreadsheet y realice el programa para guardar los datos y todo perfecto, gracias por las recomendaciones